# Fields are being cleared out when assigning an object to another objects lookup field

Tags: apex, lookup

I have a method where I am linking one record to another record and some of the fields. I am running into an issue after assignment that some fields are null.

```
Map<Id, Notification__c> notifications = new Map<Id, Notification__c>([SELECT Message__c, Name, Id FROM Notification__c WHERE Id IN :notificationIds]);
Map<Id, Notification__c> accountAndNotificationMap = new Map<Id, Notification__c>();
for(Account_Notification__c an : accountNotificationList){
    accountAndNotificationMap.put(an.Id, notifications.get(an.Notification__c));
}

for(Account_Notification__c actNotification : accountNotificationList){
        Contact_Notification__c contactNotification = new Contact_Notification__c();
        Notification__c note = accountAndNotificationMap.get(actNotification.Id);
        System.debug('The Note: ' + note);
        contactNotification.Notification__c = note.Id;

        System.debug(contactNotification.Notification__r.Name);
        System.debug(contactNotification.Notification__r.Message__c);
        contactNotificationsToUpsert.add(contactNotification);
        
}
```

When I debug "the Note" I get the values I expect to see:

> The Note: Notification__c:{Message__c=This is a test notification, Name=This is a test notification, Id=a0q17000000g11cAAA}

But when I debug the notification related fields on the contact notification they are null:

> 08:37:35.0 (197168308)|USER_DEBUG|[396]|DEBUG|null
>
> 08:37:35.0 (197202559)|USER_DEBUG|[397]|DEBUG|null

If I attempt to manually update the `contactNotification.Notification__r.Name` field or the `contactNotification.Notification__r.Message__c` fields I get an

> Attempt to de-reference a null object

How can I get these fields to populate?

Comment: is there any workflow rule or trigger that's turning it to null?

Comment: No, there are no triggers on these objects. The classes are without sharing, so field level security shouldn't be an issue either

Comment: Is this in a trigger? can you post some more code?

Comment: I found the issue. It seems as if Related Lookup fields are not populated until after the DML operation. After the DML statement they will need to be queried again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related Lookup fields are not populated until after the DML statement, and will need to be queried for again.

```
    upsert contactNotificationsToUpsert Notification_ID__c;
    Set<Id> contactNotificationIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact_Notification__c cn : contactNotificationsToUpsert){
        contactNotificationIds.add(cn.Id);
    }
    contactNotificationsToUpsert = [
        SELECT Name, Contact__c, Type__c, Id, Notification__c, Notification__r.Name, Notification__r.Message__c, Dismissed__c, CreatedDate, Notification__r.Priority__c,
            Notification__r.URL__c, Notification__r.Type__c
        FROM Contact_Notification__c 
        WHERE Id IN :contactNotificationIds
    ];
```